# ImageMagick: как правильно ужать картинку?

Tags: php, imagemagick

Необходимо с помощью ImageMagick обрезать фотографии по умному, то есть если фотография высокая по вертикали, то нужно при указании размера, скажем 100 на 100, ужать фото по горизонтали до 100 и обрезать по вертикали до 100.

Видел как это делается на других сайтах, таким образом создаются миниатюры.

У меня вот такой код:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = new Imagick('https://site.ru/foto.jpg');
$image->adaptiveResizeImage(100, 100, true);
$image->writeImage('adaptiveResizeImage.jpg');
echo $image;
```

adaptiveResizeImage - должен делать то, что мне нужно, однако фото просто ужимается по пропорциям до размера скажем 100 на 300.

Пример как нужно сделать (только тут пример про горизонтальную фото)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось проще простого, пришлось перелопатить английские форумы, в русском гугле вообще 0 информации об этом:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = new Imagick('https://site.ru/foto.jpg');
$image->cropThumbnailImage(100, 100);
$image->writeImage('adaptiveResizeImage.jpg');
echo $image;
```